# I would like some assistance with the Screw/Shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: modeling

I would like some help with my Shrinkwrap modifier as it is really weird. It doesn't apply properly around the target. This is what it looks like, along with the modifiers:

[image]

[image]

I've alternated between different settings, but to no avail...
This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Please lend me a hand. Thanks!

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello. I've attempted to share the file after pressing upload, but it seems to download the file onto my device again. What do I do? I'm new to this whole stuff. Thanks.

Comment: once you've uploaded, copy the URL address it will give, and paste it here

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c633733beff14e05b97dae343b70efc9

Comment: Your screw object is not in the file, please share the screw object as well  ;)

Comment: My apologies. https://pasteall.org/blend/bb4b269dac7b4a45adef6ba841f44bc1

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the scale of the object called *Cylinder*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I'm experiencing another problem with the same object when I apply the Solidify modifier. How can I show this to you?

Comment: create a new question?